# Creating Extranet site in O365

Tags: sharepoint-online

Users use O365. How Can I create an Extranet site in O365 and Share with external users without adding them to AD? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the best SharePoint-Features in Office365: Easy sharing of content with external users outside your organization. There is no need for an ActiveDirectory account. Users can share stuff anonymous or to any eMail-Address. If there is no Microsoft-Account registered on that Mail-Address, user must create one.

Look at this article for more details about your possibilities:

[Create an external business-sharing site in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-external-business-sharing-site-in-SharePoint-Online-c40d4670-7f6c-4719-9c6f-8dee36220a48?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)